# Html.DropDownList selected value from a list<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So I use a list of string to fill a DropDownList it work fine but for the edit part when the user goes to the edit view I need that **Relacion** have the value is have been saved on the db, selected in the DropDownList. how can dothat?

```
List<string> x = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3", " string4" };
            ViewBag.Relacion = new SelectList(x);

 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Relacion)
        </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Relacion")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Relacion)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide values to your dropdown list not only text strings
if your model does not know about relaction selected value you may use javascrip and do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

$('select[name=Relacion]').val($('#Relaciontext').val());

}
</script>
 <div class="editor-field" style="display:none" >
               @Html.TextBox("Relaciontext", ViewData["statecode"])

        </div>
   @Html.DropDownList("Relacion")

ViewData["statecode"]="string1";
```

but Ideally you need to use the selected list to populate your dropdown list and then model

by creating select list

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Relacion, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Relacion"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Telerik` controls. They have `DropDownList`, `Combobox`, `Grid` and many more. It's an open source project with many many users.

See [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox) DEMO

Comment: ok, i will look that thank you is have this solution is not perfect but it work

int a = 0;
            switch (empleadofamiliar.Relacion)
            {
                case "string1":
                    a = 0;
                    break;
                case "Esposa":
                    a = 1;
                    break;
                case "string2":
                    a = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    a = 0;
                    break;
            }
            ViewBag.Relacion = new SelectList(x, x[a]);

Comment: @Diego_DX. I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand your's English in that comment.